# headless Chrome - why doesn't it create screenshots?

Tags: google-chrome, screenshot, headless

I am following [this manual](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

But for whatever reason my command in CLI does not produce any image:

```
C:\temp2>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot http://www.google.com
```

- I have Chrome 62 (59+ needed).
- I have full rights to C:\temp2
- When I run only **C:\temp2>"C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"**, Google Chrome starts up
  which means that the path is correct.

I have Windows 7 Pro SP1 64bit.

What could be wrong?

Comment: chrome should not be visible in headless mode, i find linux to best for this sort of thing.